# report builder reverse concatenated name if one letter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, report

When I concatenate name from 4 parts if any part is one letter the hole name reversed. E.g. if the name is `'first s middle last'` it appears in pdf like `'s middle last first'`. I face this problem only when any part of name has only one letter. How can I solve this please?

Comment: Show us sample data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current code attempt.

Comment: select first_name||' '||father_name||' '||middle_name||' ' ||last_name from my_table  this is my select

Comment: You can [edit] those information directly in your question.

Comment: if first name is john father namer is george middle is D and last is karry i expect to display as john george d karyy but it appears like D karry john george

Comment: Write a `SELECT first_name, father_name, middle_name, last_name, first_name||' '||father_name||' '||middle_name||' ' ||last_name AS Result From my_table` and show us the result for a working exemple and a failling exemple

Comment: i post the example above it is simple and i used the result as a source of my field in report builder !! this problem only happen when any part is a single letter ,all the name reversed !!!

Comment: We are lacking a lot of information, because you can't expect a simple select to have different behavior base on a single letter name. I can't reproduce your issue. A select columnA|| ' ' || columnB will never give ColumnB ColumnA.

Comment: pierre this is the case if you try it your pdf will show you if one of your parts is a single letter it will reflex cancatenated parts and will not have the expected order..i am surbrised as you are  !!!

Comment: @engineera - Its this an Oracle E Biz report ? with an RTF/XSL template ? how are you generating pdf ?

Comment: i am a Beginner .. but  yes..i am using oracle 11g report builder !! is there is any way to force the name to  be displayed as its order ...i tried to make every part in a field without concatenation  but this solution make big space between each part  even when using Horizontal Elasticity variable.... any suggestion please

Comment: @engineera - try printing the name at any other location to check, if it prints correctly. Maybe there is a `rtl` alignment causing the issue

Comment: @Sudipta what do you mean by rt1 alignment ? This case only appear in report when i run it .

Comment: @engineera rtl - right to left alignment is a feature in Word processing applications used for creating RTF template files.